# SCO Unixware 2.1: Partitions bigger than 2 GB possible?

Tags: unix

I'm trying to restore a 40 GB tar backup to an ancient [UnixWare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnixWare) 2.1 box. The backup archive is on a Linux box in the same network. At this point, I'm cat'ting the tar archive through `rsh` to `tar` on the local box, which is excruciatingly slow. It would be far preferable, of course, to copy the tar archive to the local box and extract it there, but the disk add utility won't seem to let me create a [VxFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veritas_File_System) partition greater than 2 GB. I created a large VxFS partition on a Unixware 7.1 box, but I could not successfully mount it on the 2.1 box.

Is there a way around this, or is this just a limitation of the operating system?

Comment: The multi-GB files on my 32-bit Linux box disagree.

Answer (score 1):

UnixWare... Gods... 
I haven't seen one of those in years.

If I recall correctly (from the deep abyss of my memory) VxFS is limited to 2 GB on all versions of UnixWare prior to V7 (maybe V5, not sure).

64-bit on the OS has nothing to do with it. It is the index fields in the file system that have a limited size.
The newer versions of UnixWare have an updated version of VxFS that allows disks and partitions upto 2 TB.

Comment: Ok. The newer version (7) has a limit of 128 ZB (2^77 bytes). But that doesn't help for a 16 years old operating system.

Comment: @Mailq: Thanks for correcting that. I knew it was bigger. Didn't expect it to be that big :-)